# get all git remote.origin.url from exisiting clones in sub directory

Tags: bash, pipe, git

i like to write a oneliner which gets me all remote url from my cloned repositories underneath my git_repo folder (personal git root folder) and to pipe into a file
my idea was something like

```
cat */.git/config | grep remote.origin.url= >> git_repos.txt
```

but of course this does not work.

Comment: Are you trying to match a particular line in your `.git/config` file? If so, which one and why doesn't your own suggestion work? (There's no "of course" here.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will list all your remote URLs for remotes named “origin” in any git repositories beneath the current directory:

```
find . -path '*/.git/config' -execdir git remote get-url origin \;
```

It finds files named `config` inside a `.git` directory, and from every containing directory, runs `git remote get-url origin` which shows the remote URL for the “origin” remote in the current repository.

Comment: thanks that worked!